# Convert array<Byte> from camera device to Bitmap

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I am receiving array of Bytes from my camera device by calling native c++ driver.

```
Byte[] Image_Buffer=gcnew array<Byte>(3 000 000);
Camm_Acquisition(Image_Buffer);
```

Inside of it is 3 chanel color image with 12 bits per pixel.

This simple code is not working.

```
MemoryStream ^ Acquisition_Stream = gcnew MemoryStream(Image_Buffer);
Bitmap^ Acquisition_Bitmap = gcnew Bitmap(Acquisition_Stream);
```

The reason is clear: it is not standart image format. But how i need to convert it in Bitmap to show on screen.

Comment: I think the simplest (though probably quite slow) would be creating a blank bitmap with the right dimensions and converting the values for each pixel.